# Keyboard hiding modal view in react native

Tags: react-native

Im trying to build a post view that is only half big. However my keyboard keeps hiding the view and was wondering how I can fix it. After doing some research it seems like I can use KeyboardAvoidingView but I'm not too sure how or where I should put it. I want my placeholderView to go up so my actual View can sit on top of te keyboard.

```
 <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={displayThread}>
<View style = {{flex: 1}}></View> // placeholder for half view
<View style = {{flex: 1}}>
<TextInput
                style={styles.title}
                onChangeText={text => onChangeTitle(text)}
                value={title}
                placeholder = {"Title"}
                autoFocus={true}
              />
              <TextInput
                style = {styles.description}
                multiline={true}
                numberOfLines={4}
                onChangeText={(text) => onChangeDescription({text})}
                value={description}
                placeholder = "Write something ...."
              />
</View>
</Modal
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where does the modal come from? If it's a third party package it might be controlling the keyboard and you might be out of luck. Perhaps instead of using `autoFocus` you could use a hook to focus the input field after the modal has appeared.

Comment: @Slbox Modal is from the default 'react-native'

Answer (score 0):

Use `KeyboardAwareScrollView` below your View and close after your TextInput.

I use this way and works perfectly:

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
    enableAutomaticScroll
    extraScrollHeight={10}
    enableOnAndroid={true}
    extraHeight={100}
 > ...
```

customize your way.

Don't forget to add this line in your `AndroidManifest`

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

add after `android:label="@string/app_name"`